# Tableau and concurrent database connections

Tags: tableau-api

If a database is connected to Tableau and Tableau has 100 concurrent  user **sessions**, how many concurrent **connections** will there be to the  relational database. I’m looking to use a database platform that has a limit of 20 concurrent connections and I just want to makes sure this won’t conflict. This will need to be real time direct queries to a table of possible. I’m aware of caching methods in Tableau, but we need real time data.

Comment: It depends.  It depends partially on your database authentication (are the credentials saved in the data source?  Is authentication shared or does each user have their own credentials? etc).  Also, it depends on the user interactions within each visualization and how things like parameters and filters are set up.   I don't think it's a wise assumption that 20 concurrent connections to your database will be sufficient.  On live data source connections, Tableau passes queries to the database A LOT....just about every user interaction in the viz will query the database.

Comment: Thank you @devlin. If we have one connection and caching with Tableau, and run a job to refresh the cache every few minutes, will that just count as one connection ?

Comment: If it's one data source, and you don't have any kind of distributed loading going on, and you don't have concurrent queries / refreshes running at the same time..... but honestly, why not just upgrade your database?  If you can afford 100 user Tableau Licenses, surely you can afford a modern database setup?  Why have these dependencies / limitations?

Comment: Thank you. Oh sure. Yes, just need to know the inner workings in case our workloads scale up faster.